# what is the difference between glut.lib and glut32.lib? and how to take advantage of this?

Tags: c, opengl

I downloaded glutdlls for a project I am designing, but I was wondering why there were two versions of glut one that is glut32.lib/glut32.dll and the other is glut.lib/glut.dll, if there is any difference how can I take advantage of that?

[image]

Comment: glut.lib/glut.dll is probably 64 bit. What do you mean by taking advantage of it?

Comment: Are you compiling 32-bit or 64-bit code?

Comment: I am compiling 32bit normally

Comment: but I would like to compile 64bit if that's an advantage

Comment: Use 64 bit, 32 bit is just for "compatibility" and historic reasons, and no reasonable consumer machine requires it nowadays

Comment: "I downloaded glutdlls for a project I am designing" ...from where?

Comment: google "glut download" there will be OpenGL website that contains the word "glutdlls" find it and it will be a direct download.